# I want to check if $('#td1').text() === "x"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if  innerHtml have X or O , so i can not add again any thing else , but it's not working . it stop after adding the check code , I'm trying here to do a simple X O game to get more familiar with javascript and jquery .

also I'm not sure if can do this with jQuery .

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function ranFun() {
       return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
   }

   var a;

     function Elment(a) {         
         document.getElementById("td" + a).innerHTML = "O";
     }    

     function call() {
            var x = ranFun();
         switch (x) {
             case 1:case 2 :case 3: case 4 :case 5 : case 6 : case 7 : case 8 : case 9 :
                 Elment(x);
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }

     function tdElm(c) {

         if ($('#td1').text() === "x" || $('#td1').text() == "o")
             return false;
         else {
             document.getElementById("td" + c).innerHTML = "x";
             call();
         }

   }

</script>

<BODY>

<center>
<h1 >"        X ,O Game    "</h1>
<table >
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"  onclick="tdElm(1);" ></td>
       <td id="td2" onclick="tdElm(2);"></td>
       <td id="td3" onclick="tdElm(3);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td4" onclick="tdElm(4);"></td>
       <td id="td5" onclick="tdElm(5);"></td>
       <td id="td6" onclick="tdElm(6);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td7" onclick="tdElm(7);"></td>
       <td id="td8" onclick="tdElm(8);"></td>
       <td id="td9" onclick="tdElm(9);"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>

</BODY>
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: Why are you using document.getElementById when $ is already available?

Comment: Bad indentation makes others not want to help you, it shows a lack of  effort into making the question intelligible

Comment: one issue with your code is that you are testing for a lowercase o and inserting a uppercase O

Comment: did my answer answer your question / help  at all? please accept or upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is valid

```
var c = 1;
$('#td'+c).text()
```

If you want set the text of the element must use

```
$('#td'+c).text("x")
```

text method with a String param
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check both if the text is equal to `x` or not equal to `o`, one makes the other superflous.

When you set the text of an element using jQUery you supply the value in the call to `text`, you don't assign it to the return value of the function.

I assume that you want to use the `c` parameter when you check the value also.

```
function tdElm(c) {
  if ($('#td' + c).text() == "o") {
    $('#td' + c).text("x");
  }
}
```

Comment: i think this might help, but what do you do if you want this function to  do this:                                                             tdElm(c) {
  if ($('#td' + c).text() == "o") {
    //do nothing
  }else { $('#td' +c ).html='x'}
}

Comment: @M.z: Just change `==` to `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 things, as far as javascript syntax goes, are not really any different:

```
document.getElementById("td" + c);
$('#td'+c)
```

In both cases, you take a string, append a new value to that string, and then pass the result as an argument to a function.  So anywhere that would accept a string like `'#td1'` would allow accept the form of `'#td' + c`.  This isn't about jQuery, just plain javascript.

---

As for this:

```
$('#td'+c).text() === "x" ;
```

This should work, but I believe your issue is whitespace.  The text may have some whitespace around it that would make it unequal to `"x"`.  jQuery provides a `$.trim()` function to trim off whitespace for these cases.

```
if ($.trim($('#td'+c).text()) === "x") {
```

Or perhaps use a regular expression?

```
if (/x/.test($('#td'+c).text())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to read. I've whipped a quick almost working script for you to read and understand http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/MQ9Nr/

However, it seems that for what you need, you just have to check if the text is empty or not. Here are a few suggestions

- Don't set handlers from HTML
- Don't need to pass a number into the handler, the handler knows what td was clicked

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var turn = 0;
  var xos = ["x", "o"];
  $("td").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.text()) {
        return;
      } else {
        $this.text(xos[turn]);
        turn = (turn + 1) % 2;
      }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 >X ,O Game</h1>
<table >
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"></td>
       <td id="td2"></td>
       <td id="td3"></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
       <td id="td4"></td>
       <td id="td5"></td>
       <td id="td6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="td7"></td>
       <td id="td8"></td>
       <td id="td9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few things wrong with your code,

I suggest you take a look at this quick hack I put together which is working, feel free to ask questions.

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/TKq2H/4/

```
function call() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    if ($('#td' + x).text() === "x" || $('#td' + x).text() == "o") {
        call();
    }
    else {
        $("#td" + x).text("o");
    }

}
$('td').click(function() {
    var no = $(this).data('no')
    if ($('#td' + no).text() === "x" || $('#td' + no).text() == "o") return false;
    else {
        $("#td" + no).text("x");
        call();
    }
});​


<center>
<h1 >"        X ,O Game    "</h1>
<table >
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"  data-no="1" ></td>
       <td id="td2" data-no="2"></td>
       <td id="td3" data-no="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td4" data-no="4"></td>
       <td id="td5" data-no="5"></td>
       <td id="td6" data-no="6"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td7" data-no="7"></td>
       <td id="td8" data-no="8"></td>
       <td id="td9" data-no="9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
​
```