# My JQuery Code for X O Game have some trouble with cheeking innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to check if $('#td1').text() === “x”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929868/i-want-to-check-if-td1-text-x)

My Jquery Code for X O Game have some trouble with cheeking innerhtml ?
I want to check if innerHtml have X or O , so i can not add again any thing else , but it's not working . it stop after adding the check code , I'm trying here to do a simple X O game to get more familiar with javascript and jquery .

also I'm not sure if can do this with jQuery .

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function ranFun() {
       return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
   }

   var a;

     function Elment(a) {         
         document.getElementById("td" + a).innerHTML = "O";
     }    

     function call() {
            var x = ranFun();
         switch (x) {
             case 1:case 2 :case 3: case 4 :case 5 : case 6 : case 7 : case 8 : case 9 :
                 Elment(x);
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }

     function tdElm(c) {

         if ($('#td1').text() === "x" || $('#td1').text() == "o")
             return false;
         else {
             document.getElementById("td" + c).innerHTML = "x";
             call();
         }

   }

</script>

<BODY>

<center>
<h1 >"        X ,O Game    "</h1>
<table >
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"  onclick="tdElm(1);" ></td>
       <td id="td2" onclick="tdElm(2);"></td>
       <td id="td3" onclick="tdElm(3);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td4" onclick="tdElm(4);"></td>
       <td id="td5" onclick="tdElm(5);"></td>
       <td id="td6" onclick="tdElm(6);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td7" onclick="tdElm(7);"></td>
       <td id="td8" onclick="tdElm(8);"></td>
       <td id="td9" onclick="tdElm(9);"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>

</BODY>
```

Comment: repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929868/i-want-to-check-if-td1-text-x

Comment: I did repost this  because after editing this problem , people still keep answer me for the old one .

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few things wrong with your code,

I suggest you take a look at this quick hack I put together which is working, feel free to ask questions.

http://jsfiddle.net/TKq2H/2/

---

**Updated**

Please see the updated, far simpler version.

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/TKq2H/4/

```
function call() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    if ($('#td' + x).text() === "x" || $('#td' + x).text() == "o") {
        call();
    }
    else {
        $("#td" + x).text("o");
    }

}
$('td').click(function() {
    var no = $(this).data('no')
    if ($('#td' + no).text() === "x" || $('#td' + no).text() == "o") return false;
    else {
        $("#td" + no).text("x");
        call();
    }
});​


<center>
<h1 >"        X ,O Game    "</h1>
<table >
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"  data-no="1" ></td>
       <td id="td2" data-no="2"></td>
       <td id="td3" data-no="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td4" data-no="4"></td>
       <td id="td5" data-no="5"></td>
       <td id="td6" data-no="6"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td7" data-no="7"></td>
       <td id="td8" data-no="8"></td>
       <td id="td9" data-no="9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
​
```

Comment: This was really helpful ,thanks for your effort

Comment: var no = $(this).data('no') , I just want to know what this line of code do ? Please.

Comment: Can you just paste the code here?

Comment: it gets the number from the data-no attr on the td element

Comment: Do i need to Wrap this code:                                          $('td').click(function() {
    var no = $(this).data('no')
    if ($('#td' + no).text() === "x" || $('#td' + no).text() == "o") return false;
    else {
        $("#td" + no).text("x");
        call();
    }
});​
 with $(document).read(function()

Comment: yes, $(function(){ //code }); is the shorthand for document ready :)